# This element might be inside iframe from different src. Currently ChroPath/SelectorsHub doesn't support for them

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver

Tried to work with an autosuggestions list which is not interactable in java selenium. it has tag ui/li
it is not contained under any Iframe, window.

I have tried to handle this by Javascript, Actions class

[image]

The ErrorLog in consol
[image]

Comment: _This element might be inside iframe from different src. Currently ChroPath/SelectorsHub doesn't support for them_ this said by extension.. have you checked yourself ? Add the `HTML` source for the element. _I have tried to handle this by Javascript, Actions class_ can we see your code ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have tried with javascript , Actions class , Robot class also . every time getting no such element. Need to select the value from the auto populated dropdown, which is not attached in same html page where other elements are attached